# How implement autoCapitalize functionality from react native for input in react ( web )?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In **react native**, we have the ability to use the **autoCapitalize** property, which helps the user to substitute the uppercase symbol as the first letter of each word, but does not force it to always be a capital letter (that is, we can change the case if we wish)
Is it possible to implement something similar in web react?

What I mean. If the user starts to write something, then the first letter of each word should automatically become uppercase, but the user should be able to make it small if desired.

How it looks for native: https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput
( just add autoCapitalize: "words" for TextField )

Comment: Were you able to implement this?